Import Error Matplotlib require '_c_internal_utils' and actually using conda
Had this error
    {
    "name": "ImportError",
    "message": "cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\\Users\\Lenovo\\miniconda3\\envs\\lastresort\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py)",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 import os
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
      5 import numpy as np

File c:\\Users\\Lenovo\\miniconda3\\envs\\lastresort\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py:159
    155 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    157 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    158 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 159 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
    160 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
    161 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

File c:\\Users\\Lenovo\\miniconda3\\envs\\lastresort\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\cbook.py:32
     29     from numpy import VisibleDeprecationWarning
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 from matplotlib import _api, _c_internal_utils
     35 def _get_running_interactive_framework():
     36     \"\"\"
     37     Return the interactive framework whose event loop is currently running, if
     38     any, or \"headless\" if no event loop can be started, or None.
   (...)
     44         \"macosx\", \"headless\", ``None``.
     45     \"\"\"

ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\\Users\\Lenovo\\miniconda3\\envs\\lastresort\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py)"
}

and checked every other question existing like this but has different conditions. Before downgrading to python 3.11 matplotlib still works, I need to downgrade to 3.11 because 3.12 and 3.13 has requirement error (tensorflow-cpu in not exist in 3.12, cgi not exist since 3.11 or something that needs me to downgrade from 3.13)
Reinstalled Matplotlib and update it and still not working
Checked other forum this might be OS related and related to C++ engines, any possible solution?

Fixed by uninstalling matplotlib and installing matplotlib again in usual way, if necessary, delete files in ./miniconda3/envs/{env-name}/Lib/site-packages/
Will gladly edit if other details are found by other people or means

What is "usual way"?

@FlyingTeller just conda install matplotlib or pip install matplotlib. I honestly don't know why, do they always leave something after uninstalling things with conda or pip?
